# Want to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 after backing up Home folder to different partition. Is it too risky?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, reinstall

My machine is set to dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.10,but I barely ever use windows. The Ubuntu installation has been running for ages now, and I've kind of wrecked it by trying to tweak everything. I have tonnes of music/movies in my Home folder, and don't have an external hard disk, so I was wondering whether performing the following actions would be too risky:

1. Resize Ubuntu partition using GParted, to create just enough space to accommodate my home folder.
2. Copy home folder to newly created partition.
3. Format all other partitions, then install Windows 8, followed by Ubuntu 14.04.
4. Restore contents of home folder, and add the space used for backing up to the Ubuntu partition, using GParted

This is, of course, the easy way out; I really don't want to look up how to reset everything without reinstalling. Is this possible, and if it is, is it too risky?

Thanks for reading through, all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a good backup everything is safe.

There is one thing you should know. Your home folder has all your "user configured" stuff in it.

When you restore your home folder, if you want a true "fresh" install, do not copy over the entire folder. Only copy over what you need. For example don't copy back ~/.config instead copy only what you actually see using like ~/Documents,

Answer (score 0):

It probably really depends on your setup. I have done similar backups before and it worked out fairly well (save the home folder, reinstall Ubuntu, move home folder back). I'm no expert on Linux/Ubuntu, but I would imagine that some program dependencies might become an issue (you might have to reinstall/configure some things).

Overall, I would say it is safe...